# Windows Phone multiple instances of app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is it possible to run multiple instances of same application on Windows Phone 7.5 ? When I deactivate current instance and try to run a new instance via Start menu, the backround app disappears, and the new one starts in foreground with initial screen.

Is Application State preserved between such "restart" ?

Comment: have you tried with multi instances of wp7 emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it’s not possible to run multiple instances of an application in WP. When you start the application as you describe it counts as a restart of the application and no state is saved. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008(v=vs.92).aspx for detailed information.

Comment: True, but state can be saved before when the app gets obscured, so when you start anew instance (killing the previous) all you have to do is load the previous state!

Comment: Yes, off course you can save state manually, but I got the impression that the question was if state was saved automatically. I could have misunderstood the question though.

Comment: What state do you mean? ApplicationStateService.Current.State ? Or the isolated storage?

Comment: I think you are correct, @KMan, I was just adding some more info! :)

Comment: @MarcAndreson ApplicationState is not maintained in such way; you should use the IsolatedStorage to save and then load the previous state of the app

Comment: Then why MSDN manual says that when user starts new instance I must make sure IT IS a new instance", if I even don't have access to previous state?

Answer (score 2):

When you start an instance of your app and then deactivate it (by using the Start button), you have the chance to save the app state (there are Deactivated events you can you for this)

So, when a new instance is launched from the menu, the previous instance of the app gets killed and you can at this point just reload the previous saved state (if any!)

Comment: It is said that when a user starts new instance I must make the user feel that this is a completely new instance, how can I detect that this is a new instance, not activated after tombstoning?

Comment: You can use the Application Activated event to check if the app comes from tombstoning; check the image [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817008(v=vs.92).aspx)

Comment: I know this picture, I was just wondering if the ApplicationState is preserved, or a new instance starts its own life with Launching event and empty Application State and Pages' States

Answer (score 1):

Each app can only have one instance as far as I know (from my experience so far).